# URL exists in browser history, yet back button not working?

Tags: javascript, back, browser-history

This might be a pretty noob question but I am unable to find anything on SO that addresses it. I have a JS snippet similar to this in logic:

```
var return_data = hr.responseText;
if(return_data.indexOf('Are you sure') > -1){
  // if return_data contains the text "Are you sure," redirect to a new page
  var newurl = '/a-s/#/dictionary/' + conjugateterm;
  window.location.assign(newurl);
}
else {
  // if return_data contains the text "Are you sure," show returned_data as usual...
}
```

This function works fine except that it seems to hijack my browser's back button! I understand that JavaScript's `location.assign()` method does not delete browser history which should mean the back button functioning as usual, but it's not. Strangely, I can see the last visited page in the browser history as expected but clicking the back button is simply refreshing the current page instead of returning to that last page as showing in the history. Is this a known behavior of `location.assign()`? If so, is there any way to remedy the situation?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might be the use of `#` in your url, which introduces a [fragment identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier).

In fact, `/test/page#test1` and `/test/page#test2` are considered the same resource, only pointing at different places in your page. Normally those fragment identifiers aren't even sent to the webserver.